# Problema en heroku y mongodbAtalas con una app echa en Node.js y React

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, mongodb, heroku

tengo el siguiente problema. He hecho la subida de mi proyecto a Heroku y mi base de datos a mongodb Atlas.

En Heroku he creado la siguiente variable de entorno:
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://xx:xxx@plataforma.2cxua.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority

En Mongodb Atlas he creado el usuario en Database Access, he añadido la ip: 0.0.0.0/0 en Network Access.

En mi app he realizado algunos cambios en el fichero index.js

```
'use strict'


var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app=require('./app');

//variables de entorno locales
require('dotenv').config({path: 'variables.env'});

console.log(process.env.MONGO_URI);


mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

 
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI,{ useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true})
        .then(()=>{
            console.log('La conexion a la BD se ha realizado con exito');

           
        });

//LEER LOCAL HOST DE VARIABLE Y PUERTOS

const host= process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';
const port= process.env.PORT || 3900 ;


app.listen(port, host, ()=> {
    console.log('servidor corriendo en http://localhost:'+port + " " + host);

});
```

Hasta aqui todo correcto cuando abro la app através del enlace de heroku puedo crear usuarios, los cuales se ven reflejados en la base de datos, por lo que puedo usar la bd y el front de forma correcta. El problema viene cuando lo intento hacer desde otro ordenador por la URL, donde el front si se muestra correctamente pero la bd no funciona, no me muestra los usuarios, si creo usuarios no se añaden en la base de datos. Y nose que falta por realizar. Me ayudarias muchisimos. Estoy desesperada. GRACIAS!!!

Comment: Hola, no entiendo esto: *cuando abro la app através del enlace de heroku, todo OK, pero cuando lo intento hacer desde otro ordenador por la URL*. ¿A qué te refieres exactamente? Cuál es la diferencia exacta entre la URL de Heroku (que si funciona) y la URL (que no funciona)? ¿Podrías aclarar un poco más esta parte? Saludos

Comment: Por cierto esta pregunta ya la publicaste [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/400009/problemas-de-conexion-entre-heroku-y-mongodb-atlas). Evita duplicar preguntas, no es lo apropiado. Marcaré esta pregunta como duplicada. Saludos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problemas de conexion entre heroku y mongodb Atlas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/400009/problemas-de-conexion-entre-heroku-y-mongodb-atlas)

Comment: por favor, evita duplicar tus preguntas. mira [ask] y tambien hace el [tour]

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es que la base de datos que esta en mongodb atlas me funciona en heroku solo de forma local, si abro mi app en otro ordenador heroku me muestra mi web de forma correcta pero la base de datos no me funciona. No se si me he explicado bien

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que el problema lo tengas en la conexión a la base de datos de Heroku.

Seguramente estés usando la app deployada pero la base de datos de la que traes la información sea local.
Primero deberías comprobar desde la página de Heroku que tienes un add-on incorporado (ClearDB o PostgreSQL, por ejemplo) y que tienes incorporada en tu package.json esta base de datos en el script de entorno de producción

¡No te olvides de migrar las tablas una vez estés conectada a Heroku con el comando: "heroku run db:migrate"!

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta, el OP menciona específicamente que se trata de una Base de Datos MongoDB, en la cual no existen *tablas para migrar*. Por favor leer [answer]. Cuando tengas la suficiente reputación podrás [comentar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) en cualquier publicación. Saludos